# How to extract specific data from json file and save it as csv file in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

I have imported the following json file "https://pastebin.com/embed_js/PknXEGq2" and extracted all the products within it, and now i need to print each available product in this particular format:        “You can buy **Product_Name** at our store at **Product_Price**”, Product_Name is the product name truncated at 30, and Product_Price is the rounded product price in dd.d format (example: 13.34  ==> 13.3).

1. if the product is unavailable, it logs the product id and product name
2. if a clue of the product’s availability can’t be found, it logs an error
3. it saves the available products in a csv file.

   ```
    import json
    data = json.load(open('data.json'))
    save_data = []

    def get_products():
    query_access = data['Bundles']
    for question_data in query_access:
       save_data.append(question_data)
       print(save_data)


    get_products()
   ```

Comment: For a start, I think you should `import csv`

Answer (score 0):

assuming your json file looks like:

```
{
  "my_data": [
    {
      "name": "Garlic",
      "price": 2.2
    },
    {
      "name": "Potatoes",
      "price": 7.1,
      "quality": "Decent"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tomatoes",
      "price": 6.9,
      "avaiable": "No"
    }
  ],
  "useless_data": [
    {
      "some": "useless",
      "data": [
        "here"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

You code could be something like if you needed only name, price and quantity:

```py
import json
import csv

data = json.load(open("MyBeautifulFile.json"))["my_data"]
useful_columns = ["name", "price", "quality"]
default_value = ""

with open('MyBeautifulFile.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=useful_columns)
    writer.writeheader()


    for obj in data:
        row = {}
        for column in useful_columns:
            if column in obj.keys():
                row[column] = obj[column]
            else:
                row[column] = default_value
        writer.writerow(row)
```